# Devo manter o void no link ou posso deixar em branco?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, eventos

Já vi alguns links que contém a seguinte sintaxe:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="el" onclick="acao()">
```

Pelo que sei, em algumas versões do IE, isso ocasiona um erro, então pergunto se deveria corrigir fazendo isso:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="el" onclick="acao()">
```

Claro que alguns vão dizer que eu deveria fazer isso separadamente, como nos exemplos abaixo, mas eu gostaria apenas de saber se devo manter o `"void(0)"` ou posso descartar essa regra:

```
(function(){
   var el = document.getElementById('el');
   el.addEventListener("click", acao());
});
```

Usando a biblioteca como jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#el').on('click', function(){
     acao();
    });
});
```

Comment: Usar jquery sempre é a melhor solução! :D sempre!

Comment: Então, mas minha dúvida é outra... você leu a pergunta?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há nenhuma boa razão para usar um javascript: pseudo-URL (*). Na prática, isso vai causar confusão ou erros.

`<a href="#">` é uma alternativa comum que pode sem dúvida ser menos ruim.
No entanto, você deve se lembrar de retornar false a partir do seu manipulador de eventos onclick para evitar que ele faça scroll até o topo da página.

**Exemplo 1:**

```js
function foo() {
  alert('foo');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return foo();">foo</a>
```

Em alguns casos é preferível utilizar #foo para mostra/esconder elementos de forma dinâmica.

**Exemplo 2:**

```js
function foo(el) {
  var id = el.getAttribute("href");
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";
  return false;
}
```

```css
#foo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <a href="foo" onclick="return foo(this);">foo</a>
<div id="foo">div foo</div>
```

E se você pretende utilizar o jQuery pode utilizar o preventDefault:

**Exemplo 3:**

```js
$("a[href=#foo]").click(function(e) {
  foo();
  e.preventDefault();
});

function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#foo">foo</a>
```

Leitura recomendada[EN]: [Href attribute for JavaScript links: “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)